# Mule dealing with Special Characters

Tags: mule

I am writing a MEL function to deal with special characters from a JSON PAYLOAD. I am using the java.tex.Normalizer package as below

```
import java.text.Normalizer;
def convertText(data){
    String temp = Normalizer.normalize(data, Normalizer.Form.NFD).replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
    return temp;
}
```

DataMapper is complaining as below. something to do with escape sequence

```
com.mulesoft.datamapper.transform.MelRecordTransform.transform(MelRecordTransform.java:53)
    at org.jetel.component.Reformat.execute(Reformat.java:271)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: [Error: illegal escape sequence: p]
[Near : {... NFD).replaceAll("[^\p{ASCII}]", ""); ....}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your example code works in a Groovy or MEL expression component but won't work in DataMapper.  It appears that DataMapper does string literal escape processing BEFORE processing the MEL code.  This means that every two backslashes in the string will turn into one backslash BEFORE MEL processes it.  MEL then does the same thing and processes every two backslashes down to one backslash.

This can be tricky because you have 3 levels at work.

1. DataMapper applies Java escaping rules to string.
2. MEL applies escaping rules to string.
3. replaceAll() applies regex escaping rules to string.

Since you only need 2 backslashes going into level 3, then you need twice the number of backslashes you have (i.e., you went through 2 levels of escaping).  If you put in four backslashes, it will work correctly.

```
.replaceAll("[^\\\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

I verified this by just adding the string literals below into DataMapper (no replaceAll) and seeing to what it converted them.

```
"[^\\\\p{ASCII}]" converted to "[^\\p{ASCII}]"
"[^\\p{ASCII}]" converted to "[^\p{ASCII}]"
```

If you actually wanted to match the regex on a single literal backslash, you would need 8 backslashes since you'd be going through 3 levels of escaping.

Details on Java escape sequences here: [Java Escape Sequences for Character and String Literals](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.6)